# How to enable unused swap disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, swap

After some months of use I've found out that my system has no swap memory available. I urgently need it in order to build some huge software projects.

`cat /proc/meminfo` prints the following:

```
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
```

I have no swap. My laptop contains a SSD that was supposed to be only used as a fast swap memory.

`sudo fdisk -l` prints the following:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    39090175    19544064   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

As you can see the entire hard disk is marked as a Linux swap system. But why does my system not make use of it? How can I change it?

edit:

Maybe these information will help you:

`cat /etc/fstab` prints the following:

```
UUID=1274ce52-7618-40fe-9110-9778774b4d52 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
#UUID=9738bde1-2e39-44a5-8c91-4d0651fb0612 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

`sudo blkid` prints the following:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="1274ce52-7618-40fe-9110-9778774b4d52" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="System-reserviert" UUID="2A246EAF246E7E27" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="64C0725CC0723480" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="809C89129C89043E" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/fstab; sudo blkid` terminal command.

Comment: also related; http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/swapon.8.html  and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: I am wondering why my SSD (/dev/sdb) does not appear in the last list.

Comment: It appears you are using encrypted swap space. What does `ls /dev/mapper/cryptswap*` show? If it lists `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1`, what does `sudo swapon /dev/mapper/cryptswap1; fgrep Swap /proc/meminfo` say?

Answer (score -1):

check the swappiness value by :

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

and edit or add if it does not exist

```
in /etc/sysctl.conf
vm.swappiness=40
```

than reboot.

Comment: I'd recommend you read the question again and revise your answer acordingly, because this is not even close to what was asked.